# How to check if a form is submitted via javascript?

Tags: php, jquery, submit

I have this conventional submit button which submit a form like this:

```
<form method="post" id="form_submit">
...
<input class="button" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And I check if the submit button is clicked using this:

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
   //update DB
}
```

Now I have a submit link using jquery:

```
<a href="#" onclick="publish(); return false;">Submit</a>
```

JS code:

```
$("#form_submit").submit();
```

What is the alternative way here to be used here for `if(isset($_POST['Submit']))` since I'm submitting the form using javascript?

Comment: Are you submitting via AJAX/some plugin, or you want to know `.submit()` was invoked?  If you submit the form via javascript, the button that otherwise would be present, will not be in the posted data.

Comment: I'm working on a facebook app, and I'm calling a FB popup before invoking the .submit(), thanks for everyone's help, Sarfraz nailed the problem right. The hidden input is a good choice nonetheless :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, try this:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
{
 // your code.........
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should add a hidden input `<input type="hidden" name="formsubmit" value="yes" />` to the form which will always get submitted, and check for that instead of the button (*which only gets submitted if it is clicked on ..*)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem correctly that you can simply change input type to hidden.

```
<form method="post" id="form_submit">
...
<input type="hidden" name="Submit">
</form>
```

$_POST['Submit'] variable will be defined.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is "Don't do that". If you want to submit a form then use a submit button (don't do it as a side effect of clicking on a hyperlink to the top of the page). Any JavaScript you want to run can then be handled in the form's `submit` event.

If you really want to do it as a side effect, then check for the existence of any other field that you know will be set. You could add a hidden field to ensure there will be one of a given name/value combination if you like.